# Present pefect / adverbs of time

Tags: present-perfect

It's 2023 this year.
I can say "I've read ten books this year".

Can I say "I've read ten books in 2023"?

Comment: If 2023 has not ended, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you are telling the truth, it means you have read ten books since the start of 2023. You might read more in the rest of the year.

Pragmatically, and considering the number of books, and the nature of the claim, I'd assume that this actually means you have read *and completed* ten books. Otherwise it is a pretty weak claim.

Answer (score 0):

I've read three books **this week**. [the week is not yet over.]

**If the time period is still going on, you can use the present prefect. If it is over,  you cannot.**

I read three books **in 2022**. [simple past]